# Kotlin's View Binding extensions stop working after 65k method limit

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-multidex, kotlin-android-extensions

After reaching 65k method limit, Kotlin's View Binding extensions stop working and throws NullPointerException when I reference a view.

I tried to install MultiDex but it's not fixing the issue.

I'm using Android API 25, not using ProGuard and compiling for debug flavor. What can I do?

Here is an example of the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.jj.pos, PID: 5906
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jj.pos/com.jj.pos.features.authentication.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.jj.pos.features.authentication.GoogleAuthenticator.loadBusinessAndGoToMainActivity(GoogleAuthenticator.kt:42)
                      at com.jj.pos.features.authentication.GoogleAuthenticator.<init>(GoogleAuthenticator.kt:35)
                      at com.jj.pos.features.authentication.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:18)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jj.pos"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // Additional android libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    // MultiDex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    // Memory leaks
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.2'

    // RxJava
//    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    // Images loader and cache
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // Decent datetime API
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'

    // Animations
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

    // UI
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1' // -- FAB

    implementation project(':btsdk')
    implementation project(':zixng')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my Application implementation

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        MultiDex.install(this)

        // Other configs like LeakCanary, Firestore and RxJavaErrorHandler
    }

}
```

Comment: where do you reference the view? The multidex and the error are 2 different things

Comment: I reference it in an activity. It's not a particular view. It happens with any view in my entire application. It only happens when I exceed the 65k method limit even when I install multidex

Comment: @KostasDrak Thanks for the comment! I restructured the question.

Comment: can you show that activity that ou reference the textview and also how you set text? Your stacktrace only shows the crash. Furthermore since you minSDK is 23 you do not need the multidex dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning the project solved the issue.